# Run a VBA Macro multiple times based on a column (from a table on an Excel file)

Tags: excel, vba

Please help me run a macro multiple times.

I have a Macro that does what I want, but I have to manually do the first step, filtering and selecting the data.

I am doing this by going into the Sheet "dataALL," where it has five columns.
Then I filter by column 3 and copy all those into Sheet "data" where there is another table with the same column names 1-5.
Run the macro based on that table, which creates a separate sheet with all the data conditioning, and once done, clear the table.
Then I go back to the "dataALL" sheet, filter the second one of column 3 and repeat for all of them (over 100)

Where:
Sheets "dataALL" has the table "DataTable2"
Sheet "data" has the table "DataTable"
The name of the macro to run each time is "AA_MACRO"   (Application.Run "'WORKBOOK.xlsm'!AA_MACRO")

```
Sub ZZZZ_Macro1()

   ' FILTER NAME1
    Sheets("dataALL").Select
   ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTable2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTable2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1 _
        :="NAME1"
    Range("DataTable2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("data").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    'RUN MACRO
    Application.Run "'WORKBOOK.xlsm'!AA_MACRO"
    'CLEAR TABLE
    With Sheets("data").ListObjects("DataTable")
        If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            .DataBodyRange.Delete
        End If
    End With
    Sheets("dataALL").Select
    
    
    ' FILTER NAME2
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTable2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1 _
        :="NAME2"
    Range("DataTable2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("data").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    'RUN MACRO
    Application.Run "'WORKBOOK.xlsm'!AA_MACRO"
    'CLEAR TABLE
    With Sheets("data").ListObjects("DataTable")
        If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            .DataBodyRange.Delete
        End If
    End With
    Sheets("dataALL").Select
End Sub
```

Is there a chance that instead of copying the data filtered every time to make a macro that filters and runs it for me?

Please let me know if anything needs to be clarified!
Thanks, and anything helps!

Comment: Start the macro recorder, do all the above steps (up to the second filter) then stop the recorder. Put the generated code in a loop to achieve what you want.

Comment: Is there a chance to make a macro that does xy for you? Is that your question? Then the answer would be: Most Definetely. Will someone deliver a full solution to your problem? Unlikely. Do as Super Symmetry said. Record it with the macro recorder, look at the generated code and modify it to your needs. If you need help understanding or modifying the generated code, ask a new question.

Comment: @Super Symmetry  I have attached the suggestion of recording a macro for the first two.  I edited and ran it, and it works great. Would you mind helping me to turn it into a loop?